# What are the procedures for a high school graduate to only do exams at university for upper division courses, graduate and become a PhD candidate?

Tags: university, exams

Suppose that a high school student has mastered physics and math subjects taught at university at the level expected for a graduate student. The student has done research in collaboration with a professor in conformal field theory and published 8 papers in various physics and math journals. After graduating from high school, this student does not want to spend several years at university following courses and doing homework for subjects he has already mastered. It should be possible to do exams in a limited number of subjects, say, analytical mechanics, advanced electrodynamics, advanced quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, general relativity, advanced statistical mechanics, and then graduate within one month. The student then wants to pursue a PhD.

How do universities handle such requests from students?

Comment: Is there a specific region you're asking this for? I think there might be a big difference between countries how they would handle this.

Comment: For many cases that I know of when someone is extremely gifted in some subject (usually mathematics related, but that may simply be due to my biased reading tendencies), the person is working through college classes while in high school and often tend to complete a college degree, or most of one, while doing so -- [typical example of what I often read about](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2017/05/12/kid-genius-brothers-11-and-14-graduate-high-school-and-college-this-weekend/) and see *Terence Tao Education* [here](https://onlinemathdegrees.org/terence-tao/).

Comment: *It should be possible to do exams in a limited number of subjects, say, analytical mechanics, advanced electrodynamics, advanced quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, general relativity, advanced statistical mechanics, and then graduate within one month.* --- As @Jeroen said, you should say what country this is, because these courses are not even required for a physics degree in the U.S., and aside from that, much more than physics and math is required for a degree (probably 2/3 of courses one takes), such as various humanities and social science and other course distribution requirements.

Comment: In the end, this is probably something that is really decided on a case-by-case basis very dependent on the university so I doubt this is something that we can answer. Contacting universities and asking might be the only way to go.

Comment: In my comment, where I said "because these courses are not even required for a physics degree in the U.S.", I suppose analytical mechanics should be excluded, as this is typically (always?) required for a physics degree in the U.S. Here I'm talking about [this level course](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0534494927), NOT [this level course](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201657023). (I'm not excluding "advanced electrodynamics", because I assume you are talking about [this level course](https://www.amazon.com/dp/047130932X).)

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in general, as it will be based entirely on how the university statutes deal with exceptional cases, which will depend 100% on what university we are talking about.

Comment: *typical example of what I often read about* --- I just realized that the newspaper article I linked to is NOT an example of what I was talking about, because in the article one brother is graduating high school and the other from college. However, I did recently read about a simultaneous high school and college graduation this past May-June graduation period, and I've seen others in various past years. Not that this really has all that much to do with the OP's actual local circumstances, however . . .

Comment: 1) Universities have a set of rules, e.g.  the number of required credits for graduation. This is often defined at some extent by the law of given country and the body responsible for accrediting university programs, too. It is not that simple that people think you are smart. 2) While I understand the cool factor of having three PhD at an age of 10, in my opinion it has relatively little practical advantage. Once one is in at undergraduate program, has access to resources for research, collaboration, even grants. Doing research in your free time as undergrad is pretty simple.

Comment: Please don't write questions in the annoying "suppose X hypothetically Y" format, it's very confusing to read.

Comment: CV until a country is provided.

Comment: This is specific to each university. If this is done regularly, they will have a policy. Read the Handbook of the graduate school you are interested in or contact the Dean of the Graduate School. I suggest The University of Chicago, which has done this in the past.

Answer (score 4):

For a direct answer to your question, most universities don't have any policies for this because it is so rare. But many will permit exceptions to the general "rules" for exceptional cases. It might actually be easier at the graduate level than for undergraduate, but I have no data (duh).

But, if you want a university to make an exception, you need to convince them that it is appropriate to do so. The hardest thing, I suspect, is getting heard in the first place. It is likely that a direct request from yourself will go nowhere. You need advocates for your case.

One way to approach this is to get one or more of your teachers to make contact with one or more faculty members at a university on your behalf. It is best if they are already known to them, but you use what you have. And, your collaborator on the papers would be a great advocate if they are willing.

If you can get in the door (hard), then you might be able to have some math and/or physics faculty members give you an oral exam to explore the extent of what you know. You might have a series of conversations in which you are asked to explain things (and solve problems) that are somewhat difficult. If you can get to that stage, those faculty members might be willing to serve as your advocate(s) for admission.

This might be easier in the US than elsewhere, since the undergraduate education is more generalized than specialized and even in  the "major" it is mostly fundamental knowledge that is covered. The course in "Advanced Analysis", for example, isn't the last word on the subject. Furthermore, most US doctoral programs start with advanced coursework, not dissertation research.

However, what you will miss by doing this (for a US student) is the broad education in subjects outside the major that might contribute to a fuller life in the long run. Learning some history and language and social science and (lots more) has value in itself, which is why the US undergrad program looks like it does.

If you are good enough you can probably get it done, but the search might be long and difficult to find an opening.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems much more plausible to me for a university to waive a prior degree requirement to take on a PhD student with incredible potential than to simply award them that prior degree to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I think that is correct. I considered only the question of admissions. In any case, it would be hard (at best) to give an undergraduate transcript to such a student.